# hibernate infinite loop over selecting a clients request

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

This is my model classes and when I use this code it will start an infinite loop

```
Set<Request> requests = Clients.getRequest();
```

**Client  class**

```
public class Client extends User {


    @Column(name = "registrationcomplete")
    private boolean registrationcomplete = false;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Request> requests = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<File> files = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Call> calls = new HashSet<>();

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<UserFeedBack> userFeedBacks = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<RightMessage> rightMessages = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    private Set<AdminConfirmation> adminConfirmations = new HashSet<>();

    public Client() {
    }

}
```

**Request class**

```
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uid;

    @Column(name = "requestnumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long requestNumber;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private boolean deleted = false;

    @Column(name = "creationdate", updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Long creationDate;

    @Column(name = "modificationdate", updatable = true)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Long modificationDate;

    @Column(name = "requeststatus")
    private RequestStatus requestStatus;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientid", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Client client;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "request")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Call> calls;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "request")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<RequestLawyer> requestLawyers = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "request")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<ConsumptionPack> comments = new HashSet<>();

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "request")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<FeedBack> feedback = new HashSet<>();

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fileid")
    private File file;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "request")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Notification> notifications = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "request")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions = new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "advicetypeid", nullable = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private AdviceType advicetype;


    public Request() {
    }


}
```

**LawyerActivity  class**

```
public class LawyerActivity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uid;

    @Column(name = "typeUser")
    private LawyerActivityType type;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;


    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    private Long creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyerid")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Lawyer lawyer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "docId")
    private Doc doc;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fileid")
    private File file;

    public LawyerActivity() {
    }
```

**Doc  class**

```
public class Doc {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uid;

    @Column(name = "checksum")
    private String checksum;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "doctype")
    private DocType docType;

    @Column(name = "mimetype")
    private MimeType mimeType;

    @Column(name = "hashcode")
    private String hashCode;

    @Column(name = "length")
    private String length;


    @Lob
    @Column(name="data")
    private byte[] data;

    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    private Long creationDate;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private boolean deleted = false;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyerid")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Lawyer lawyer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "callid")
    private Call call;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "doc")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<LawyerActivity> activities = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fileid")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private File file;

    public Doc() {
    }

}
```

**File  class**

```
public class File {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uid;

    @Column(name = "filenumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long fileNumber;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "creationDate")
    private Long creationDate;

    @Column(name = "modificationdate")
    private Long modificationDate;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private boolean deleted = false;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientid",nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Client client;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "file")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Request> requests = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "file")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Doc> docs = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "file")
    private Set<SharingPerspectives> sharingPerspectives = new HashSet<>();


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "file")
    private Set<LawyerActivity> activities = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "file")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Idea> ideas = new HashSet<>();

    public File() {
    }

}
```

and this is my user class

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID uid;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name = "username",unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email",unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "score")
    private int score;

    @Column(name = "avatarhashcode")
    private String avatarHashcode;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active = false;

    @Column(name = "usedapp")
    private Boolean usedapp = false;

    @Column(name = "avatarverify")
    private Boolean avatarverify = false;

    @Column(name = "mobilenumber", unique = true)
    private Long mobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "verificationcode")
    private String verificationCode;

    @Column(name = "creationdate", updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Long creationDate;

    @Column(name = "modificationdate", updatable = true)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Long modificationDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "roleid")})
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Complain> complains;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Setting> settings = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<AccessEntry> accessEntries = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Offcode> offcodes_from = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user2")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Offcode> offcodes_to = new HashSet<>();



    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<InvitedUser> invitedUsers = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<AssignDiscount> assignDiscounts= new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Reminder> reminders = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<SharingPerspectives> sharingPerspectives = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<RightMessage> rightMessages = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<UserPopularity> userPopularities = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizationid")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Organization organization;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Doc> docs = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "userorg",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "orgid")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userid")})
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Organization> organizations = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(UUID uid, long mobileNumber) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //taha
    @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id")
    private Wallet wallet;
}
```

Comment: You posted a lot of code, but not the class Clients, and not its method getRequest(). So itf the problem is indeed an infinite loop in that method of that class, how can we help?

Comment: I am using lombok and getters like getRequests(). are automatically produced by lombok. and the client class is my first class in question.

Comment: There is no way a getter generated by Lombok contains an infinite loop. Tell precisely what you're actually doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. If you got an error, of course post the exact and complete error stack trace. Also, the code that you say causes an infinite loop is `Clients.getRequest()`. What is `Clients`. According to the Java naming conventions, it should be a class, and `getRequest()` would be a static method. But I see no such class or method in what you posted.

Comment: that capital C in client was a mistype the exact code I am using is Set<Request> requests = client.getRequests();  and this problem happens when a lawyer has an activity selecting request leads to select a file then a doc and finally a activity then the infinite loop start.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem happens because of @OneToMany relationship

Add the annotation @JsonIgnore in the attribute clients at the class Request:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientid", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
    private Client client;
```

Comment: I have tried that before but the result is still the same. and I am not serializing the classes and instead i am using dto .